# "cout" does not work with string

Tags: c++

Hello guys I have a problem with printing the content of a string in Visual C++ 2013
The code is simple as you see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   
    ifstream file("d:\\t.txt");
    if (file.is_open())
    {
      string a[5];
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
      {
        file >> a[i];
      }
    }
    cout<< a;
    system("pause");
}
```

I get the following error:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Project3, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Source.cpp
1>c:\users\malatrab\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\project3\source.cpp(14): error C2065:   'a' : undeclared identifier
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

So please any ideas about this problem. The compiler can not recognize the string variable a.

Comment: `a` is not a `string` : you used a loop to write it, use a loop to read it.

Answer (score 2):

there is nothing named `a` in the scope where you're using it.

also note that `cout` does not directly support output of arrays (other than arrays of `char`). passing such an array directly directly to a `cout` output operation it decays to pointer to first item. so you need to do some looping to output those strings, when you have fixed the main issue.

Answer (score 2):

To put `a` in scope, initialize it before the if statement.
Also, `a` is an array and you must specify the position of what you want to access.
In this case the loop is specifying values 0 through 4, one at a time.

```
 ifstream file("d:\\t.txt");
 string a[5];
 if (file.is_open())
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
          {
             file >> a[i];
          }
    }
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
 {
    cout << a[i];
 }
 system("pause");
```

Answer (score 1):

`a` is not an `std::string`, it's an array of `std::string`. However, the compiler is really complaining about scope. You declared it within the `if { }` block, but try to use it in the outer block. Secondly, you don't have to deal with arrays here, especially if you intend on reading from a file. Use `std::vector` instead, there is virtually no overhead.

```
std::vector<std::string> a;
if (file.is_open())
{
  std::string word;
  while (file >> word)
    a.push_back(word);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Array a has block scope of the statement if

```
    if (file.is_open())
    {
      string a[5];
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
      {
        file >> a[i];
      }
    }
```

Then the control is passed outside the compound statement of the if the array will be destroyed and the identifier a will not be visible.

Also there is another problem. I think you want to output each element of the array in this statement

```
    cout<< a;
```

instead of the address of the first element of the array.

Rewrite main the following way

```
int main()
{
    const size_t N = 5; 
    string a[N];

    ifstream file("d:\\t.txt");

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i )
        {
            file >> a[i];
        }
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i )
    {
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

You could use range based statement to output the array

```
for ( const auto &s : a ) cout << s << endl;
```

Also you should write C headers like

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
```

As no declaration from header `<cstdio>` is used in the program then you may remove the corresponding #include directive.